# How to add facebook iframe code directly to block?

Tags: 6, blocks, social-network

I am trying to display a facebook plugin as a block. I created a new block from the block admin page, and in the "Text" for the block entered the following iframe code and tried a couple of things (none worked) - all show the raw iframe code in the block.

1. Tried 'Input Format' as FULL HTML (doesnt work)
2. Tried 'Input Format' as "PHP" (doesnt work, even tried adding  tag.)

Following is the iframe code I am trying:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fzuck&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=verdana&amp;width=450&amp;appId=133506150025748" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: while hideous, using the PHP input format and <?php print '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.co......'; ?> *should* work fine...just be sure to wrap it all in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Jimajamma - I tried this, didn't work. THanks for the help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use "Full HTML" input format and paste the iframe snippet in the *source view* of the block (e.g click "Source" on rich-text editor toolbar first )

Answer (score 1):

please make sure that you use full html (no filtering) and make sure you direct html and not using that through TinyMCE or any wysing Editor